# What is some good literature about the different parameters between languages?

Tags: syntax, principles-and-parameters

I'm looking for some reading material on the technical differences regarding parameters and structures between languages. I'm trying to understand how languages like Turkish word on a syntactical level in comparison to languages such as English or French (something a bit deeper than SOV as opposed to SVO).

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: A popular introduction to parameters is 'The Atoms of Language' by Mark C. Baker.

Comment: There is a lot of work done in non-technical esp. non-generative typological approaches which described different surface patterns. "Principles and Parameters" refers to a specific (now supplanted) theory of generative syntax – it's a specific generative theory of how languages could differ. Are you interested in the broader non-generative theory or some version of the generative account?

Comment: Both would interest me. I do find theories alternative to the mainstream generative approach to be quite fascinating. Do you have any recommendations for any specific articles or even terms/key words to look into?

Comment: Start with [WALS](https://wals.info/), and then look at various ways of defining and presupposing the uses of such parameters to see which ones look sensible to you in the light of the kind of variation that exists. There is no standard theory of parameters, and since they're mathematical-ish, everybody has their own version and their own theories about them. Think spreadsheets instead of paradigms.